# How to find specific pattern in a paragraph in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find a specific pattern in a paragraph. The pattern must contain `a-zA-Z` and `0-9` and length is 5 or more than 5. How to implement it on Python?

My code is:

```
str = "I love5 verye mu765ch"
print(re.findall('(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{5,})',str))
```

this will return a null.

Expected result like:

```
love5
mu765ch
```

the valid pattern is like:

```
9aacbe
aver23893dk
asdf897
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions

Comment: Have you googled it ? try something ?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}` ?

Comment: Thanks, @OlvinRoght but I need regex and operation. please see my code

Comment: @Noyon, you can use regular expression from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70583574/10824407#comment124774625_70584000) comment.

Comment: What do you mean by a paragraph? The question states that it should contain a-zA-Z and 0-9, but can it also contain other characters as well, and then 5 or more in total? Perhaps like `(?<!\S)(?=[^\d\s]*\d)(?=[^\sa-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])\S{5,}` https://regex101.com/r/O6556L/1

Comment: Many many thanks @OlvinRoght . Your answer perfectly working.

Comment: @Noyon, better to use updated version of my regular expression provided by [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70583574/10824407#comment124776455_70584000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done with some programming logic and a simple regex:

```
import re

string = "I love5 verye mu765ch a123...bbb"

pattern = re.compile(r'(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]).{5,}')

interesting = [word for word in string.split() if pattern.match(word)]
print(interesting)
```

This yields

```
['love5', 'mu765ch', 'a123...bbb']
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/QEb8sl).

Comment: Too many actions, if we are using regex, then let regex do all job. [`\b(?=[A-Za-z\d]*?\d)(?=[A-Za-z\d]*?[A-Za-z])((?:[A-Za-z\d]){5,})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/yrqv6Y/1) should work with [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

Comment: @OlvinRoght: Not too many actions *per se*. A huge fan of regular expressions here (see the golden regex badge) but be aware that the overall code must remain readable - which is more likely with a shorter pattern and a comprehension.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Note that you don't need all those capture/non capture groups, and you can omit the non greedy quantifiers `\b(?=[A-Za-z]*\d)(?=\d*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z\d]{5,}\b`

Comment: @Thefourthbird, yes, you're right, didn't actually optimized it, wrote first version appeared in my mind. Thanks for optimization though.